# Как парсить html с использованием QtWebEngine?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

В относительно недавно вышедшей версии Qt 5.6 более не поддерживается библиотека QtWebKit (уже давно отмечена, как `deprecated`), которая ранее позволяла осуществлять парсинг DOM-дерева вебстраниц. Кто знает, как это возможно реализовать при помощи новой QtWebEngine?

Comment: Попробуйте libxml2, который поддерживает в том числе и html

Comment: @PavelParshin зачем? несколько дней назад обновился до 5.6, в астистанте уже достаточно информации по вебэнжину, щас вот почитаю, может быть, помогу человеку.